# an amazing stuff with flash or javascript?

Tags: jquery, flash

today,i saw an amazing effect, which is on this site http://www.ffsjgzs.com/imageshow.swf

an amazing effect, i want to do it. could anyone tell me how to do it? using jquery or flash?

Comment: i think the downvote is a bit harsh +1 to counter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [jQuery UI Coverflow](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/) for that kind of effect (among many others)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that using jQuery is with a gallery plugin - [there are loads on this site](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/).  They might not be quite as slick as the one you like but they are still pretty damn good to say they are really just javascript!

Comment: if it uses javascript when i unable javascript,why the effect still can access? thank you.

Comment: the effect on that website doesn't use javascript - it is flash, you can tell by the url, it ends in .swf (flash file), I meant the jQuery plugins I linked to use javascript